# how to convert BSON to JSON on python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

im catching program packets and i got this bson: `GwAAAAJJRAADAAAAU1QAElQAseX+LO++2QgAEG1jAAEAAAAA`

Also i found a site to convert it to json, but its on java script, how to make similar using python?

site: http://mcraiha.github.io/tools/BSONhexToJSON/bsonbase64tojson.html

code:

```
import base64
import bsonjs
b64String = base64.b64encode(data)
packet = b64String[16:]
print(packet)
```

Comment: [that can help you](https://pypi.org/project/python-bsonjs/). [Here](https://sodocumentation.net/pymongo/topic/9348/converting-between-bson-and-json) you can find an example as well

Comment: great @KlimBim, before that we need to convert his string into base64 decoded and do the `bsonjs.dumps`, I have added the answer below and let me know your thoughts pal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is can solve your need

```
import bsonjs
import base64
yourString = "GwAAAAJJRAADAAAAU1QAElQAseX+LO++2QgAEG1jAAEAAAAA"
outJSON = bsonjs.dumps(base64.b64decode(yourString))
print(outJSON)
```

output `Dict`:

```
{ "ID" : "ST", "T" : 637750756710999473 }
```

Let me know if you have any issues please